# How to Save complex Arrayobjects to device using NSKeyedArchiver swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

I want to save an array of any class (e.g let array = SymptomsModel) type into device using NSKeyedArchiver in swift .

I Know how to save an array if SymptomsModel class contains all variables with primitive data types , but don't know how to save it if also contains an array of any other class as its property

Below I have explained my problem with the help of example , please go through it and provide solution.
I have a class

```
class SymptomsModel: NSObject, NSCoding ,ResponseJSONObjectSerializable   {
            var slug:String?
            var name:String?
            var images:[Sym_images]?
            var videos:[Sym_videos]?

    struct Keys {
            static let Name = "name"
            static let Slug = "slug"
            static let Images = "images"
            static let Videos = "videos"
         }

     required init(json:SwiftyJSON.JSON) {
         self.slug = json["slug"].string
         self.name = json["name"].string

         self.images = [Sym_images]()
         if let imagesJSON = json["images"].array {
                for(imagesJSON) in imagesJSON {
                    if let newImages = Sym_images(json: imagesJSON){
                        self.images?.append(newImages)
                    }
                }

          }

          self.videos = [Sym_videos]()
          if let videosJSONArray = json["videos"].array {

                for(videosJSON) in videosJSONArray {
                    if let newVideos = Sym_videos(json: videosJSON){
                        self.videos?.append(newVideos)
                    }
                }

           }
       }


  init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
     self.name = dictionary[Keys.Name] as? String
     self.slug = dictionary[Keys.Slug] as? String
     self.images = dictionary[Keys.Images] as? [Sym_acc_images_objects]

     self.videos = dictionary[Keys.Videos] as? [Sym_acc_videos_objects]

   }
func encodeWithCoder(archiver: NSCoder) {
    archiver.encodeObject(name, forKey: Keys.Name)
    archiver.encodeObject(slug, forKey: Keys.Slug)

    archiver.encodeObject(images, forKey: Keys.Images)
    archiver.encodeObject(videos, forKey: Keys.Videos)
}
required init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder) {
    super.init()
    name = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Name) as? String
    slug = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Slug) as? String
    self.images =  unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Slug) as? [Sym_acc_images_objects]
    self.videos =  unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Slug) as? [Sym_acc_videos_objects]
   }
```

and a PersistanceManager class to save the data with NskeyedArchiver as

```
    class PersistenceManager {

    class private func documentsDirectory() -> NSString {
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectory = paths[0] as String
        return documentDirectory
    }

    class func saveNSArray(arrayToSave: NSArray, key: String) {
        print(" saveNSArray key : \(key)")
        let file = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(key)
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(arrayToSave, toFile: file)

    }

    class func loadNSArray(path: String) -> NSArray? {
        print(" loadNSArray key : \(path)")
        let file = documentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
        let result = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(file)
        return result as? NSArray
    }
}
```

And Here is my implimentation of saving and then retreiving the array

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
  var ArraySymptom = [SymptomsModel]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ArraySymptom = loadArray()

    //saving data in device
    PersistenceManager.saveNSArray(ArraySymptom, key: "Symptom")


   //loading data from device
       if let value = PersistenceManager.loadNSArray("Symptom") as? [SymptomsModel]  {
            let images = value[0].images
            print("images : \(images)")
            let slug = value[0].slug
            print("slug : \(slug)")
       }              
  }
```

Here am able to get the value of slug but not able to fetch images value.
It might be happening because slug is of String type and Images is of Custom Class type .
Please suggest me the way i can get it done .
Is is possible to save these type of arrays with NSKeyedArchiver , so that i can access images value just by retreiving ArraySymptom from device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Silly mistake it was**

I was getting nil in Images because it was decoded with wrong key , it was copy paste mistake

The Error was in this function..

```
required init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder) {
super.init()
name = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Name) as? String
slug = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Slug) as? String
self.images =  unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Slug) as? [Sym_images]
self.videos =  unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(Keys.Slug) as? [Sym_videos]
```

}

And the correct decoding must be

> self.images =  unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(**Keys.Images**) as?
>   [Sym_images]
>
> self.videos = unarchiver.decodeObjectForKey(**Keys.Videos**) as?
>   [Sym_videos]

Comment: Hi preeti , did you just  used archiver.encodeObject(videos, forKey: Keys.Videos) for video or added any archiver for video itself??